# How would I create an access token for the NFL Shield API?

Tags: rest, api, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0

The NFL appears to have an API service here: https://api.nfl.com/docs/getting-started/index.html

Accessing the API endpoints requires obtaining an OAuth2 access token. Which, if I am not mistaken, requires a client_id and client_secret.

I have read through the documentation and I am not sure how I would obtain a client_id and client_secret. Is there something I am missing to create these?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Working example of implementing 'Token Based Authentication' using 'JSON Web Token (i.e. JWT)' in PHP and MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29179790/working-example-of-implementing-token-based-authentication-using-json-web-tok)

Comment: It is not a duplicate. It is just that NFL had their Shield API documentation open to public but nowhere does it specify how to get authorization to the API.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: wish i coudl figure this out also!

Answer (score 4):

Finally got an answer on this. The documentation does say that the API is public and free for everyone, but they changed that policy and haven't updated the documentation.

> Hi Dominic,
>
> Thanks for reaching out. As of Feb. 18th, the NFL has secured the APIs and will only grant access to contractual partners.  Unfortunately, if you are NOT a NFL Partner you will no longer have access to the feeds or able to obtain access to this feed.
>
> Thanks,
> Jonathan Vu
> Product Operations Manager