# Generating access token for NFL api

Tags: rest, api, authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization

NFL has an api service. **link**: https://api.nfl.com/docs/getting-started/index.html

For making api calls we need an Oauth2 access token.

To generate it we need to hit **/oauth/token** endpoint with parameters client_id and client_secret in body.Now I cannot find any documentation on how to generate the client_id and client_secret.

Another way I found was to create a new user which just requires you to pass necessary parameters like username,password,etc and in turn gives a new access token.But doing this way also gives a unauthorized 401.

So I am doing it wrong.If someone has used this api in past , please do share how you did it.I also found another question here on the same topic **link** : [How would I create an access token for the NFL Shield API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40680510/how-would-i-create-an-access-token-for-the-nfl-shield-api)  but it does not have any answer.I am sharing the links to two docs related to authentication.

https://api.nfl.com/docs/identity/oauth2/index.html

https://api.nfl.com/docs/identity/register/index.html

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I'm stuck with the same problem.

Comment: No,so I chose to go with this api http://developers.stattleship.com/#football-games