# Accessing the NFL API

Tags: rest, oauth, oauth-2.0

Has anyone had success accessing the NFL's API? I'm looking for a (free) source for live NFL data and this API looks promising...but I cannot figure out how their auth works.

You need a `client_id` and a `client_secret` to get an `access_token`, which is then used to register a user
https://api.nfl.com/docs/identity/oauth2/index.html

https://api.nfl.com/docs/identity/register/index.html

But nothing in the docs talk about how to get the id/secret. Maybe it's just not available to public.

Comment: I've tried in the past as well. Looks like it's not available to the public. however, there are other endpoints. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53147256/generating-access-token-for-nfl-api)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I emailed them and got the same answer...kinda annoying that there's no mention anywhere that it's private.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I moved on to try nflgame(https://github.com/derek-adair/nflgame) which pulls from that same data. So far so good. I'll shoot you an email since this is all to support a fantasy game.

Comment: oh wow. nice find! This will save me tons of time in the future.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you access the NFL's API's?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33489239/how-do-you-access-the-nfls-apis)

Comment: Confirmed not available to public here; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40680510/how-would-i-create-an-access-token-for-the-nfl-shield-api

Comment: @d219 yeah I gave up on the NFL API. nflgame was a good alternative but unfortunately the NFL has made changes which break that as well. I have yet to find a good alternative that doesn't cost $5k/season

Comment: @enesefuu - this might be of use (just trying it  myself) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63438767/where-to-find-nfl-xml-schedule-data-for-2020/63446470#63446470

Comment: @d219 that looks super promising. Thank you!

Comment: @enesefuu - no worries, in addition (depending on what you're after) the Sleeper API is open for read (as long as you limit the number of calls). Looks good for player info (documentation is here - https://docs.sleeper.app/)

Comment: Has anyone figured this out? I tried creating an account at developer.nfl.com but I couldn't even verify my account to access the docs. Is there any other way to get player stats and game info out there?

Comment: I have gotten access. but i don't want to pust publicly cause i don't want them to shut down the API methods I use. if you can find a way to email me i can get it to you